# Color a few cells according to 1 cell's value

Tags: excel, vba, cell, background-color, conditional-formatting

I have a hourly plan where time of employees' meetings automatically appears from an other sheet.
I need it to be marked with specific color according to meeting's lenght.
Ex.

`"`A1=0,5 then A1 is blue
if A1=1 then A1 and A2 is blue
if A1=1,5 then A1, A2, A3 is blue and etc.`"`

I only find info how to mark specific cell using conditional formating or VBA, but don't know how to apply formula to the whole table

Answer (score 1):

### Conditional Formatting

Select the range where you want this applied, e.g. `A1:A10`, or `A1:J10` if you want this to work in the other columns, too.

On the `Home` tab select `Conditional Formatting > New Rule`.
In the `New Formatting` window select *Use formula to determine which cells to format*.
In the text box below enter this formula:

```
=A$1/0.5>=ROW()
```

Press the `Format` button below and in the `Format Cells` window select the `Fill` tab. Select a color and press `Ok` 3 times.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I need to adjust formula to the section C7:X26, so in conditional formatting formula I wrote :'=C$1/0,5>=ROW( )'
But it's not working :(
Any Ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: Where is the value? Is it in `C7` for all the columns, or is it for each column in the 7th row i.e. `C7, D7, E7,...`?

Comment: Select the range `C7:X26`, select `Home>Clear>ClearFormats` and try: `=$C$7/0.5>ROW()-7`.

Comment: Value can be in any cell in range C7:X26.
So if C7 would be 1, then I need C7 and C8 to be filled with color.
If D9 would be 0,5, then I need only D9 to be filled with color.

Function =$C$7/0.5>ROW()-7 doesn't do anything as well :(

Comment: If it does nothing, then you forgot to select a color. If the `D9` part, you are mentioning, is not a typo, I can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: Okay, you showed me the right direction! It works, just I need to create separate formatting for each of rows and use formulas in this way:
 =$C$7*2>ROW()-6 then other one
 =$C$8*2>ROW()-7 and etc.
THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! You really saved my day (or even a week..) :)